# Hive JDBC client throws SQLException

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, client, hive, sqlexception

I am connecting to a hive installation using a JDBC client code. I have created a test table with two columns(column1, column2) both string type. When i try executing simple queries like "select* from test" i get result in java program but queries with where clauses and other complex queries throw the following exception.

"Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask"

I have tried changing permissions of hdfs directories where file is present, /tmp on local directory but this didn't work.

This is my connection code

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://"+host+":"+port+"/default", "", "");

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

Error is thrown at **executeQuery()** method

Checking the logs on server gives the following exception:

java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.(Cluster.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.(Cluster.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.(JobClient.java:457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:973)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:893)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer$HiveServerHandler.execute(HiveServer.java:198)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive$Processor$execute.getResult(ThriftHive.java:644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive$Processor$execute.getResult(ThriftHive.java:628)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:206)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.IOException(Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.)'

The queries work when run on a command prompt but not in JDBC client.

I am stuck on this. Any suggestions would be helpful.

**UPDATE**

I am using cloudera CDH4 hadoop/hive distribution. The script that i ran is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop/client
HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive

echo -e '1\x01foo' > /tmp/a.txt
echo -e '2\x01bar' >> /tmp/a.txt

HADOOP_CORE={{ls $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop*core*.jar}}
CLASSPATH=.:$HADOOP_CORE:$HIVE_HOME/conf

for i in ${HIVE_HOME}/lib/*.jar ; do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i
done

for i in ${HADOOP_HOME}/*.jar ; do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i
done

java -cp $CLASSPATH com.hive.test.HiveConnect
```

I had change **HADOOP_CORE={{ls $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-*-core.jar}}** to **HADOOP_CORE={{ls $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop*core*.jar}}** as there was no jar file in my hadoop_home starting with hadoop- and ending with -core.jar. Is this correct? Also running the script gives the following error

**/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop*core*.jar}}: No such file or directory**

Also i have modified the script to add hadoop client jars to classpath as the script threw the error that hadoop fileReader not found. So i added the following as well.
for i in ${HADOOP_HOME}/*.jar ; do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i
done

This executes the class file and runs the query "select * from test" but fails on "select column1 from test".

Still no success and the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Since, it is running fine with the hive shell, can you check if the user with which you are running the hive shell and the java program (with JDBC) are the same?

Next, Starting the Thrift Server
cd to where hive is -
Issue this commands -

```
bin/hive --service hiveserver &
```

you should see -

> Starting Hive Thrift Server

A quick way to ensure the HiveServer is running is to use the netstat command to determine if port 10,000 is open and listening for connections:

```
netstat -nl | grep 10000
tcp  0  0 :::10000         :::*          LISTEN
```

Next, create a file called `myhivetest.sh` and put the follwing inside
and replace **HADOOP_HOME**, **HIVE_HOME** and **package.youMainClass** according to your requirements-

```
    #!/bin/bash
    HADOOP_HOME=/your/path/to/hadoop
    HIVE_HOME=/your/path/to/hive

    echo -e '1\x01foo' > /tmp/a.txt
    echo -e '2\x01bar' >> /tmp/a.txt

    HADOOP_CORE={{ls $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-*-core.jar}}
    CLASSPATH=.:$HADOOP_CORE:$HIVE_HOME/conf

    for i in ${HIVE_HOME}/lib/*.jar ; do
        CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i
    done

    java -cp $CLASSPATH package.youMainClass
```

Save the `myhivetest.sh` and do a `chmod +x myhivetest.sh`. You can run the bash script using `./myhivetest.sh`, which will build your classpath before invoking your hive program.

Please follow the [instruction here](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hiveclient.html) for details.
There are two ways embedded mode and standalone mode.
You should look for the standalone mode.

**For your information:**
Hive is not a extensive query engine akin to the DBMS like MySQL, Oracle and Teradata etc.
Hive has got limitations on the extent of complex queries you can make, like very complex joins etc.
Hive runs Hadoop MapReduce jobs when you do a query.

[Check this tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual) for what type of queries are supported and which are not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The query i am using for testing is "select column2 from test where column1='somevalue'". This query runs a map/reduce job and returns the results when i run this on hive command line but this throws exception when running in java JDBC client. Could this be any permissions issue or any dependency missing?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Let me get back to you.

Comment: Check I have edited my answer a bit considering you can successfully run the query using hive shell.

Comment: i run the hive shell from root user in a centos server. The java code is executed in eclipse IDE on my local machine. I tried executing a runnable jar of the code on server with root user but the same exception. I have also posted an exception i get in hive-server log file when running through jdbc.

Comment: Please try running the jar using - hadoop jar yourjar.jar ...
That way, hive might get the configuration files for hadoop.

Comment: I think you also don't need to make runnable jar and normal jar would do the trick! I have added a link to the answer. Please check that out.

Comment: Running the code as hadoop jar jarfile.jar also throws the same error. I executed the jar on the server with hive. The hadoop job does not get submitted if  run through java

Comment: I tried "sudo -u hdfs  hadoop jar testjar.jar" which gave exception testjar.jar not found(Permission Denied). Then i ran simple hadoop command as "hadoop jar testjar.jar" which gave the above errors. I also tried adding all hadoop/hive jars in their lib directories to the classpath as "java -cp all-Class-path-jars -jar testjar.jar" which again threw the same exception

Comment: Last try from my side. I have edited my answer. Please check and reply if anything's not clear. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the script you have mentioned in the answer. I have updated the question with the results. Please let me know if anything is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I have managed to resolve the issue.

This error popped up when I was running the hive jdbc client on a hadoop cluster with /user accounts set up.
With such a environment set up, the ability to run map-reduce jobs were all based on permissions.

With the connection string being wrong, the map-reduce framework was not able to set up staging directories and trigger off the job.

Please look at your connection string [if this error is popping up in a hadoop-cluster setup].

If the connection string looks this way

```
Connection con = DriverManager
                .getConnection(
                        "jdbc:hive2://cluster.xyz.com:10000/default",
                        "hive", "");
```

Change it to

```
Connection con = DriverManager
                .getConnection(
                        "jdbc:hive2://cluster.xyz.com:10000/default",
                        "user1", "");
```

where user1 is a configured user on the cluster setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues. I am trying to query Hive using Oracle SQL Developer (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) combined with a third-party JDBC driver as described here: https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/entry/oracle_sql_developer_data_modeler. Yes, I know that I could use Hue to do this but I interact with many other databases, including Oracle, and it is nice to have a rich client that I can save SQL queries and simple reports directly on my machine.

I am running the latest version of Cloudera CDH (5.4) on a cluster on AWS.

I was able to issue simple queries such as "SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_07" and receive a result, but running "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SAMPLE_07" would throw a JDBC error. I was able to solve this by creating a user in Hue, and entering this user information in the Oracle SQL Developer connection information dialog. After doing this, I was able to run both queries.

What was confusing about this is that I was able to run a simple SELECT statement and received no error -- what I am used to is either a) I can log into a system to run queries or b) I can't. Strange that it "sort of" works without the correct user ID but I guess one of those strange Hadoop things.